# Open source reporting library for Java

Tags: open-source, library, java, reporting

I'm looking for a good reporting tool for Java which is easy to implement to my Java desktop program for generating reports. It may or may not be like Crystal Reports but hopefully it is. Looking for something that is easy to use as well. Thanks in advance for the suggestions.

Comment: You are looking for a Java library, right? What kind of reports should it produce, just charts, or multi-page documents with titles, table of content, etc? Should it perform data pivot, or even business intelligence, aggregate cubes, etc? Please assume that nobody knows Crystal Reports nowadays, so "like Crystal Reports" will not get you good answers.

Comment: Sorry.. just contents in multiple pages then.. simple data from database.. nothing too complicated at the moment.. thanks